# How to pass credentials to activator command securely

Tags: scala, shell, nexus, credentials, activator

We have a requirement where we need to pass the username and password of our nexus to the Scala activator command inside shell script. Currently we are using via file: .credentials_att_nexus, which we use to hard-code credentials inside that file. We need a secured approach andp pass credentials dynamic via job level

Command USed:

```
activator '-Dsbt.boot.credentials={/home/}/.ivy2_tt_nexus/.credentials_tt_nexus' -Dsbt.boot.properties=/home/.ivy2_tt_nexus/sbt.boot.properties
```

Credentials_tt_nexus:

```java
username:t23247
password:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Please help to pass the credentials mentioned above directly via command line inside jenkins

TIA